# Neo4j O'reilly book examples

Tags: neo4j

The Graph Databases O'reilly book has incomplete examples that are not working. I have tried the create Shakespeare graph which was successful. However, when I query the graph that I just created, the query doesn't recognize some entities. Here is what I am referring to:

```
START theater=node:venue(name='Theatre Royal'), 
newcastle=node:city(name='Newcastle'), 
bard=node:author(lastname='Shakespeare')
MATCH (newcastle)<-[:STREET|CITY*1..2]-(theater) <-[:VENUE]-()-[:PERFORMANCE_OF]->()-[:PRODUCTION_OF]-> (play)<-[:WROTE_PLAY]-(bard)
RETURN DISTINCT play.title AS play
```

The **author** was never part of the CREATE statement. What am I missing?

I would truly appreciate your help!

-Ahmed

Answer (score 4):

You can download the code for most of the examples, including the Shakespeare example, from here:

https://github.com/iansrobinson/graph-databases-use-cases

This code includes the steps necessary to index the data.

Comment: You can also paste the `CREATE` statements into the Neo4j console (http://console.neo4j.org/r/blank and replace the index names like `author` with `node_auto_index`.

Comment: I tried the node_auto_index as follows:


START theater=node:node_auto_index(name='Theatre Royal'), 
 newcastle=node:node_auto_index(name='Newcastle'),  
 bard=node:node_auto_index(lastname='Shakespeare')
 MATCH (newcastle)<-[:STREET|CITY*1..2]-(theater) 
 <-[:VENUE]-()-[:PERFORMANCE_OF]->()-[:PRODUCTION_OF]-> (play)<-[w:WROTE_PLAY]-(bard)
WHERE w.year > 1608
RETURN DISTINCT play.title AS play

The query didn't return any records. I am so frustrated :-)

I really want to use Neo4J but if I can't get it to work my advisor will ask me to use Titan or Oracle NoSql Would be a loss.

Please help!

Comment: Did you enable the node auto index in your server and configure the right properties to be indexed _before_ you created your data?

Comment: Here is my neo4j.properties file:

keep_logical_logs=true

# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
node_keys_indexable=name,age,venue,city,author

# Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false
relationship_auto_indexing=true

# The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
relationship_keys_indexable=name,age,venue,city,author

I will remove the data and construct the graph again.

Comment: @MichaelHunger

I did remove the previous nodes, restarted the server, and constructed the graph. I got no records returned :(  

Any other suggestion?